# r shiny load data from API

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a shiny app to load some data from different API, to do directly some analysis like graph...
I searched on the website of shiny i didn't find a way. My data doesn't want to load on the graph, i think it's because i load data directly on the server page, because i want load only the data wanted... The data comes from the ecb package from european central bank, which load the data from their API. This my code :

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
#library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

library(ggplot2)


ti<-c("PIB","MM_M3","Taux_d_Inflation")
data<-data.frame("ICP.M.U2.N.000000.4.ANR","BSI.M.U2.Y.V.M30.X.I.U2.2300.Z01.A","MNA.Q.Y.I8.W2.S1.S1.B.B1GQ._Z._Z._Z.EUR.LR.GY")
colnames(data)<-ti


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Evolution Economique"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("Indicateur Europe"),
      selectInput("chiffre","Indicateur:",
                  choice=ti),
      #downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
      actionButton("go","Load"),
      hr(),
      helpText("Donnees Banque Centrale Europeenne")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("graph")
    )
  )
))
```

**Server**

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(ecb)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  observeEvent(input[["go"]],handlerExpr = {
    compa<-input$chiffre
    compa<-as.character(compa)
    temp<-data[[compa]]
    temp<-as.character(temp)
    temp<-data.frame(Date=ymd(as.character(get_data(temp)$obstime),"%Y-%m"),Valeur=get_data(temp)$obsvalue)
    temp<-get_data(temp)
    temp<-data.frame(Date=temp$obstime,Valeur=temp$obsvalue)
    temp
    })


  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(temp,x=~Date,
            y=~Valeur,type="scatter",mode="lines")
    #layout(title="Quaterly evolution")
  })


})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your graph isnt aware of the `temp` object as its initiated locally within the `observeEvent`, try to use `eventReactive` instead:

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  temp <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    req(input$chiffre)
    compa<-input$chiffre
    compa<-as.character(compa)
    temp<-data[[compa]]
    temp<-as.character(temp)
    temp<-data.frame(Date=ymd(as.character(get_data(temp)$obstime),"%Y-%m"),Valeur=get_data(temp)$obsvalue)
    temp<-get_data(temp)
    temp<-data.frame(Date=temp$obstime,Valeur=temp$obsvalue)
    temp
  })


  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(temp(),x=~Date,y=~Valeur,type="scatter",mode="lines")
    #layout(title="Quaterly evolution")
  })


})
```

Comment: i'm trying use this, with a function writtent in ui.r and eventReactive call the function but my try and your code give me the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"